# Proving a much stronger version of AM-GM for three variables

Tags: inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, buffalo-way

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3406957/631742), @MichaelRozenberg stated the following inequality without proof:

> **Theorem.** For all non-negative $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$,
>   $$a^6+b^6+c^6-3a^2b^2c^2\geq16(a-b)^2(a-c)^2(b-c)^2.$$

In my answer below I give a complete brute-force proof. However, more elegant proofs are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will use the [Buffalo method](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/the-buffalo-way/): By symmetry of the inequality, we can assume without loss of generality that $a\le b\le c$. So we can substitute $a=x,b=x+y,c=x+y+z$ for some non-negative reals $x,y,z$.

Putting this in our inequality and expanding results in

$$\color{green}{12 x^4 y^2 + 12 x^4 y z + 12 x^4 z^2 + 28 x^3 y^3 + 42 x^3 y^2 z + 54 x^3 y z^2 + 20 x^3 z^3 + 27 x^2 y^4 + 54 x^2 y^3 z + 87 x^2 y^2 z^2 + 60 x^2 y z^3 + 15 x^2 z^4 + 12 x y^5 + 30 x y^4 z + 60 x y^3 z^2 + 60 x y^2 z^3 + 30 x y z^4 + 6 x z^5} + \color{blue}{2 y^6 + 6 y^5 z - y^4 z^2 - 12 y^3 z^3 - y^2 z^4 + 6 y z^5 + z^6}\geq 0.$$

The green part is automatically greater or equal than $0$ because the $x,y,z$ are non-negative. Also,
$$\color{blue}{2 y^6 + 6 y^5 z - y^4 z^2 - 12 y^3 z^3 - y^2 z^4 + 6 y z^5 + z^6}=y^6+(y-z)^2(y+z)^2(y^2+6yz+z^2)\geq0.$$

This achieves a proof.

Answer (score 7):

I meant the following reasoning.

Let $a=\min\{a,b,c\},$ $b=a+u,$ $c=a+v$ and $u^2+v^2=2kuv.$

Thus, by AM-GM $k\geq1$ and

$$\sum_{cyc}(a^6-a^2b^2c^2)=\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2+c^2)\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b)^2\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{2}(u^2+v^2)(u^4+v^4+(u^2-v^2)^2)=(u^2+v^2)(u^4-u^2v^2+v^4).$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that:
$$(u^2+v^2)(u^4-u^2v^2+v^4)\geq16(u-v)^2u^2v^2$$ or
$$2k(4k^2-3)\geq16(2k-2)$$ or $$4k^3-19k+16\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$4k^3-19k+16\geq3\sqrt[3]{4k^3\cdot8^2}-19k=\left(12\sqrt[3]{4}-19\right)k>0.$$

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?